# How to Echo Metadata Value in Currency Format

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox, post-meta

I have a Custom Post Type with a Metabox and an input Text field for adding "Price" to the posts. Now I would like to display the input value which can be like 49 or 59 like 49.00 or 59.00 so far I have this code to output the meta as:

```
$meta = get_post_custom($post->ID);
echo '<h5> $'.$meta['price'][0].'/h5';
```

but this just return the value as $49 or $59. Can you please let know how I can make it to be render as $49.00 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

WordPress core has [`number_format_i18n()`](http://queryposts.com/function/number_format_i18n/) function, which allows to set number of decimal digits and apploes appropriate formatting in line with site's locale.

However note that it is not specific to *money* and there can be more peculiar requirements to handle such.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the php core function `money_format()`

the code should look something like this:

```
$meta = get_post_custom($post->ID); // value=123456

setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');

echo money_format('%i', $meta) . "\n"; // USD 1,234.56
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You should use the php [number_format](http://pk1.php.net/number_format) function which does what you exactly want.

The second parameter of `number_format` sets how many decimal point you want after the number.

Example:

```
<?php
echo number_format(123, 2); //123.00
echo number_format(123, 4); //123.0000
```

So with your code it would be:

```
$meta = get_post_custom($post->ID);
echo '<h5> $' . number_format($meta['price'][0], 2) . '</h5>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Rahil Wazir's answer can do the job but I think is really better use the [money_format functio](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php)n from PHP*.

*Remember that this site is for Wordpress specific questions.